# Set a variable based on output from applescript function

Tags: applescript

I am using an app called Qbserve. It returns what amount of time you are productive and distracted during the day.

If you write an applescript like so:

```
tell application "Qbserve" to getProductiveTime
```

it will output to the console the number of seconds you have been productive.

I want to take and calculate (productiveTime/(distractedTime+productiveTime) and based on that, it will copy a one text file or another over my /etc/hosts so that sites such as youtube are blocked (maybe if it is less than 0.5).

I am not sure how to set a variable from this function though in applescript. I tried

```
set productive = tell application "Qbserve" to getProductiveTime
```

but that doesn't seem to be how applescript works and I haven't found any examples of how to syntactically do this.

Comment: You are right that is that the syntax is incorrect. You can rewrite it as `tell application "Qbserve" to set productive to getProductiveTime`. The thing to remember with AppleScript is that the `=` sign is not used for assignment, but instead used for equality. Even for equality the word "equal" is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `to` isn't what we need. After stating the application name, the functions can be used to set the variables, so we can do the following:

```
tell application "Qbserve"
    set productive to getProductiveTime
    set neutral to getNeutralTime
    set distracting to getDistractingTime
    set total to productive + neutral + distracting
    set percent to productive / total
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    if (percent < 0.5) then
        display dialog percent
    endif
end tell
```